# How is it possible to have an autocomplete feature in Bash dropdown?

Tags: linux, bash, git-bash, dropdown

Some similar to this: https://github.com/donnemartin/gitsome

I am not talking about tab autocompletion in bash, but rather a dropdown for autocompletion in bash?

Comment: This could be a good question, but the "Any suggestion for any libraries?" part is firmly off-topic. See #4 at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for guidance on how to improve it.

Comment: You have a program that does what you want. Why not read its source?

Comment: (The answer is roughly "lots of curses magic"; that's not easy to compress into something that's a good fit for SO).

Comment: Charles Duffy, I have read the code base, and its not striking to me, and hence only I have reached out to the larger community for help.

Comment: The short form is that it's **not** in bash. It's a superset of xonsh, a Python shell that does the aforementioned magic.

Comment: ...there's a reason they emphasize that shell as optional -- it's not bash-compatible if you're doing anything interesting at all.

Comment: Thanks so much! Thats mostly the direction i needed! Thansk so much!